# If/Then statement in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to make a simple Excel sheet for a medical office: Put in the patient's name, date, type of treatment, etc., and whether it is a Gold or Purple treatment (the company makes you buy treatments so they get revenue) it will transfer to one of two other sheets I made. I know some C++, so I made a simple If statement that works. However, if it is a purple treatment and I want a gold treatment, it will show the whole line blank. Is there a way to make it delete that blank line in an If/Then statement?

Thanks for your help.

P.S. I would prefer not to have to code at all, but if it is required I will do it.

Comment: how about show some code ..

Comment: Just because you already know some C++ doesn't mean your question has anything to do with C++. Retagging.

Comment: Matz: I don't have any code in it at the moment, is there a way to upload a sample of the excel spreadsheet for you to look at?
Syam: sorry, I am new to this website
Pnuts: could you possibly help me with some code that could do that? I have no experience using C++ with Excel.

Comment: In Excel you can use VBA directly. There is no need to use C++. That would be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without code as you want it.

If you want, you can use a pivot table however. On each sheet filter by the proper filter (either plan) and you will have only the relevant data.

Comment: Would it work if I were to say (in Excel):   =IF(Info!E4="Gold","Yes",E5)? Therefore, if it wasn't Gold it would go until the next time it was gold, creating an infinite loop?

Comment: Not exactly. You can try it and you'll see. This will not be very clean.

Comment: Explain the -1. This is a legit answer. It would work better using a pivot table if he can. Using standard Excel functions is almost impossible in this case without having to make workarounds. The other answer at the moment mentions using OFFSET() which is a volatile function and can seriously slow the workbook which is not the case with a pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

This, what you are describing, is possible to achieve by searching the next line in which the "purple" treatment occurs, and referencing it by `offset(X42,row_difference,col_difference)`. You would have to do the counting in a separate column (or a group of columns), and then hide them once the sheet works.